# Android Wear onTapCommand CanvasWatchFaceService lag

Tags: android, kotlin, wear-os, watch

I created a New Project on Android Studio that has the 'app' and 'wear' module. I installed it on my Fossil Sport via adb debugging over bluetooth.

The watch app is just a digital watch face with a tap command that opens up a new WearableActivity via intent.

Here is the code for the onTapCommand inside the CanvasWatchFaceService:

```
override fun onTapCommand(tapType: Int, x: Int, y: Int, eventTime: Long) {
            when (tapType) {
                WatchFaceService.TAP_TYPE_TOUCH -> {
                    // The user has started touching the screen.
                }
                WatchFaceService.TAP_TYPE_TOUCH_CANCEL -> {
                    // The user has started a different gesture or otherwise cancelled the tap.
                }
                WatchFaceService.TAP_TYPE_TAP ->{
                    // The user has completed the tap gesture.
                    val intent = Intent(this@DigitalWatchFace,MainActivity::class.java)
                    startActivity(intent)
                }
            }
            invalidate()
        }
```

Tapping the watch face on first try works perfectly. If you quit the WearableActivity by swiping, the 2nd tap opens up again the WearableActivity smoothly.

The problem is, if you tap the watch face to open the WearableActivity  then quit the WearableActivity via hardware button and then tap again, it takes 3 seconds at least to open. Which we can't have on our app.

Here is the code for the MainActivity it is just a simple showing of the xml layout:

```
class MainActivity : WearableActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        // Enables Always-on
        setAmbientEnabled()
    }
}
```

I tried this in a Fossil Sport watch and TicWatch E2 but the problem still persists. If this is a Wear OS lag issue is there any workaround to prevent this lag?

Thanks in advance to anyone who could help!

Comment: Is the lag in your watch face receiving the `onTapCommand`, or in opening the activity? If you're not sure, adding some logcat entries should tell you.

Comment: Yes it is receiving the onTapCommand but it takes at least 3 seconds during the lag

Comment: If you're not even receiving the event for multiple seconds, there's probably nothing that you can do about it. Truth is, Wear OS is often just laggy.